# Perl sha-256 authentication for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, perl, authentication

Im using the Perl module DBD::pg to connect to Postgres

DBI connect('dbname=db;host=host;port=5432','user',...) failed: authentication method 10 not supported

```
#connect to database
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$host;port=$port",
                    $username,
                    $password
                   );
```

Comment: If you have the latest DBD::Pg, you should probably file a bug report.

Comment: @choroba makes sense lol

Comment: @Joycel can you share some of your `pg_hba.conf` and the subroutine you are using to call `DBI->connect`?

Comment: Issue resolved for my case had to download latest lib files from pg v.12, install them in the C:\Strawberry\c\bin, then run the following commands in the directory:pexports libpq.dll > libpq.def
dlltool -dllname libpq.dll --def libpq.def --output-lib ..\lib\libpq.a                           the files are the following: libiconv-2.dll libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll libpq.dll libssl-1_1-x64.dll libintl-8.dll

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL authentication method 10 not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474420/postgresql-authentication-method-10-not-supported)