# PostgreSQL authentication method 10 not supported

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to follow the [diesel.rs tutorial using PostgreSQL](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/). When I get to the Diesel setup step, I get an "authentication method 10 not supported" error. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Hi chasahodge! It may be helpful if you update your question with the full error message and detailed explanation when the error appears.

Comment: You are using [scram authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html) on the server and an outdated client library that doesn't support it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name (love the name; one of the first songs I learned on the guitar): That is the whole Error Message.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 19):

You have to upgrade the PostgreSQL client software (in this case, the libpq used by the Rust driver) to a later version that supports the `scram-sha-256` authentication method introduced in PostgreSQL v10.

Downgrading `password_encryption` in PostgreSQL to `md5`, changing all the passwords and using the `md5` authentication method is a possible, but bad alternative. It is more effort, and you get worse security and old, buggy software.

Comment: I’m using PostgreSQL 13. I changed the pg_hba.conf file setting the Authentication Method to trust and then the password_encryption to md5 in the postgresql.conf file. Both files reside in the /share/postgresql folder. Haven’t changed the password since I edited those files so I’ll try that now and see what happens

Comment: Don't. Upgrade the client software.

Comment: @chasahodge Have you managed to resolve this issue?

Comment: Same issue here, upgrading solved the problem for me, thanks.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you mean by client any software ? My colleagues use an  [http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/extras/archive/](old soft) to import datas inPostGIS. I can't update libs myself. If I understand well either I change method in postgresql.conf AND pg_hba.conf (pg13) with md5 or we have to abandon the plugin we were used to use ?

Comment: @Leehan Abandon that software. Anything that old is a liability, not only security-wise.

Comment: Not that simple, more than 40 colleagues are concerned.

Comment: Then revert to `md5`.

Comment: postgres version is 15.4 and pq version is 1.10.9 and I'm still having the same issue

Comment: @Pyarel I don't know what you mean by pq 1.10.9. You must be using an old client version.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database using Go (Golang) and I have updated the Go driver (pq) that allows your Go application to communicate with the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: @Paroo That Go driver is in turn linked with an old version of `libpq.so` (or - worse - statically linked). That's the component you need to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your response @LaurenzAlbe. I will surely upgrade that and give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a Rust-specific question; the issue applies to any application connecting to a Postgres DB that doesn't support the scram-sha-256 authentication method. In my case it was a problem with the Perl application connecting to Postgres.

These steps are based [on a post](https://rtcpan.develooper.com/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=130644).

You need to have installed the latest Postgres client.
The client bin directory (`SRC`) is "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin" in this example. The target (`TRG`) directory is where my application binary is installed: "C:\Strawberry\c\bin". My application failed during an attempt to connect the Postgres DB with error "... authentication method 10 not supported ...".

```
set SRC=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin
set TRG=C:\Strawberry\c\bin

dir "%SRC%\libpq.dll"         # to see the source DLL
dir "%TRG%\libpq__.dll"       # to see the target DLL. Will be replaced from SRC

cp "%SRC%\libpq.dll" %TRG%\.

cd %TRG%
pexports libpq.dll > libpq.def 
dlltool --dllname libpq.dll --def libpq.def --output-lib ..\lib\libpq.a

move "%TRG%"\libpq__.dll "%TRG%"\libpq__.dll_BUP # rename ORIGINAL name to BUP
move "%TRG%"\libpq.dll "%TRG%"\libpq__.dll       # rename new DLL to ORIGINAL
```

At this point I was able successfully connect to Postgres from my Perl script.

The initial post shown above also suggested to copy other DLLs from source to the target:

```
libiconv-2.dll
libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll
libintl-8.dll
```

However, I was able to resolve my issue without copying these libraries.

Comment: Other alternatives is just to update file libpq.dll into the newest one thats support SCRAM-256.
You could find related specific library in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/List_of_drivers#Drivers.

In my-case i'm update the libpq.dll from https://www.exefiles.com/en/dll/libpq-dll/

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to PostgreSQL 12 helped