# Problem with server upgrade from 12 to 13 and 32-bit applications

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a 64-bit Postgres server and 32-bit Windows applications. This worked perfectly until I upgraded Postgres from 12 to 13. The new server works well but applications raise an error `authentication method 10 not supported` on login.

I edited `13/data/pg_hba.conf`, replaced the authentication method from `scram-sha-256` to `md5` in all entries, and restarted the server but the problem remained.

I think I need a new version of 32-bit `libpq.dll` but cannot find any newer than this from Postgres 10. Two questions. Will a newer version of `libpq.dll` solve the issue? And if so, where can I find it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL authentication method 10 not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474420/postgresql-authentication-method-10-not-supported)

Comment: @AndrewMorton - thanks, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is analogous to that described in [PostgreSQL authentication method 10 not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64474420/1995738). An additional difficulty in my case was that I could not get the dlls from the server installation due to a 64-bit vs 32-bit incompatibility. I have just found a solution and post it that may be useful to others in the same situation.

Download the binaries for Postgres 10.17 Win x86-32 from [this page](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries). You can find the file `libpq.dll` in `lib` folder but it is not enough as it needs two other (new) libraries: `libcrypto-1_1.dll` and `libssl-1_1.dll`. Copy the libraries and make available to your 32-bit applications. These three libraries are necessary for proper login. The `lib` folder contains more libraries that your application may need.

Note that the authentication method `scram-sha-256` is safer than `md5` so it is no reason to replace it in the way described in the question.