# Postgis Plugin: authentication method 10 not supported Connection with kosmtik

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm working on a project with the kosmtik tool together with osm2pgsql to be able to generate data for OPENS STREET MAP directly from my postgres database, and I'm having this connection problem when I make requests to the database, they are being accessed by the file localconfig.js and together with project.mml

Has anyone had a similar problem or worked with this tool to be able to use it in OSM ??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get what you are referring to with "this connection problem". Can you add some more context, like e.g. the actual error messages you get from the application or database server side?

Answer (score 0):

From [PostgreSQL authentication method 10 not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474420/postgresql-authentication-method-10-not-supported), you can understand that your client cannot authenticate using `scram-sha-256`, and from `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD` in https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres, you get that `scram-sha-256` is the default auth method when using postgres 14 and later.

So, you can either update the postgresql client you use, or downgrade postgres to v13. You could also choose to disable passwords or use md5 auth method on postgres.

It does looks like kosmtik uses mapnik, which has [Unable to connect to Postgresql 14 with scram-sha-256 password hashing · Issue #4283 · mapnik/mapnik](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/4283).